# iPhone 6S - Not getting Push Notification and Badge icon related to OS Updates

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, notifications

I bought an iPhone 6S three months back. Earlier I was not aware that I would get push notifications regarding iOS updates. However, later I became aware of this thanks to a friend. Since buying my iPhone, Apple has released 3 updates and I had not received a single notifcation of these.

**If I go manually and check for software update, then I can see it**. Why are other devices getting notififcations regarding iOS Updates and I'm not? I have **formatted** my iPhone 3 times and the latest one was done by Apple service and they set it up as new iPhone.

Please help me out regarding this issue.

Comment: How long after the update was released were you waiting to receive the update info. Sometimes for me it will take up to 2 days before my phone automatically checks for updates

Comment: @NoahL i have waited for more than 2 weeks, i haven't. if i check manually also, then also badge icon is not getting update only i can see, there is software update and ready to install. if it shows than y not push and badge icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this type of question is that it can only be verified as *resolved* under the right circumstances.

Although you say you have reset the iPhone three times, and once at an Apple service centre, it's not clear what type of reset was done. My advice is to follow these steps to try and resolve your issue.

1. Connect your iPhone to your computer and launch iTunes (if it isn't already open). Note: You may need to enter a passcode or *trust this computer*.
2. Select your iPhone when it appears in iTunes. (Note: If you're prompted to update iOS **do not download/install the update**.
3. Manually do a full backup of your iPhone to your computer (i.e. not just to iCloud). You can do this by clicking on the *Back Up Now* button. This may take some time depending on how much data you have.
4. Once your backup is complete, disconnect the iPhone from your computer.
5. On the iPhone go to **Settings > General**
6. Swipe up and tap on the **Reset** option at the bottom
7. Tap on **Erase all Content and Settings**
8. Follow the prompts to erase/reset your iPhone
9. Once you've reset your iPhone, reconnect it to your Mac or PC and launch iTunes (if it isn't already open). Note: You may need to enter a passcode or *trust this computer*.
10. Select your iPhone when it appears in iTunes
11. When prompted, choose to Restore your iPhone from the backup you made at Step 3
12. Follow the prompts to restore your iPhone

Once these steps are complete you will have hopefully resolved your issue.

At the time of writing this, iOS 10.2.1 was just released (hence why at Step 2 I didn't want you downloading/installing the update if prompted).

If you haven't already installed this update, then you should get your notification soon. On the other hand, if iOS 10.2.1 was already installed then you won't know if these steps have resolved your issue until Apple releases the next update.

**EDIT re: Timing**

I just wanted to add a bit of info on the timing of notifications relating to iOS updates.

Typically, after an iOS update is release, users should get a badge notification with a '1' that sometime in the first 48hrs - 72hrs. However, an actual push notification may not come until quite some time after and only if your device hasn't been updated yet.

Using myself as an example, I have an iPhone 6s which I've had since September 2015 (it's now Feb 2017). In that whole time I've never had a push notification about an iOS update because I always update my iPhone fairly quickly. However, my wife who also got an iPhone 6s at the same time as I did, did get a push notification for iOS 10 at some point (weeks after iOS 10 launched) because she was still on iOS 9.3.5 and was in no hurry to update (I'm usually her guinea pig with these things). However, she did eventually update from iOS 9.3.5 to iOS 10 because the notification was relentless annoying her (and because iOS 10 was working well for me).

In summary, what I am saying is that a badge icon *should* appear within 72hrs of the official release, but that a push notification message may take weeks and only if arrive if you haven't updated.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. reset means completely formatted iPhone and setup as new iPhone. and I have already installed 10.2.1 manually because it was security updates, so what i will do, i will follow ur steps and once more i will try and hopefully wait for next updates. I think so what ever u have suggested in ur points i have done those points earlier and if it comes to apple service centre, they off course has followed these steps.  Incase it does not work, so where is the mistake, whether apple will replace my iPhone. what is the working solution

Comment: I don't think Apple would have chosen that particular _reset_ option. I assume this on the basis that the option I'm suggesting is, as you put it, a full reformat of your iPhone, and Apple staff avoid doing this unless they're fairly certain the user has a full backup. It's much more likely that Apple only performed the _Reset All Settings_ option or the _Reset Network Settings_ option. Regardless, I would still follow these steps and just wait.

Comment: However, if you happen to hear of a new update, do not go into Settings. I would give it a few days, as your timezone also affects things. Also, users will typically have a badge notification with a '1' that should appear sometime in the first 48hrs - 72hrs after an update. However, an actual push notification may not come until quite some time after if your device hasn't been updated yet. In a sense, you're actually lucky. I have come across many users who become extremely frustrated once the push notification starts, because if they _don't_ want to update it just keeps annoying them.

Comment: @ Monomeeth i have another device (iphone 7), in which i will get immediately push message regarding os update, and in my friend device, iphone 6s

Comment: Are both your iPhone 7 and iPhone 6s with the same cellular network? Are they usually connected to the same Wi-Fi networks? Are you using the same Apple ID on both? And are they both set up the same way in terms of iCloud?

Comment: yes same network and same wifi. apple id's s common in iPhone 7 and  any way they use same wifi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52850/discussion-between-imran-and-monomeeth).